# Drupal doesn't send emails

Tags: email, drupal-6

I have a Drupal site installed on a remote server. Drupal tries to send an email when a user registers containing a new password, but it appears that it cannot send any email.

Are there any configuration settings in Drupal or on the server to resolve this?

Comment: This is probably a better reference:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38255/how-can-i-stop-drupal-from-sending-e-mails-of-any-kind

Answer (score 0):

From drupal site:

- The site email address (used when sending notification emails, and the default for most all modules that send emails) can be set via the Site Configuration > Site information page (admin/settings/site-information).
- Many modules that send emails offer a setting for an address to send emails from, and optionally a reply-to address. Check module settings and docs for email-intensive modules.
- Your server's PHP config file (php.ini) defines the outbound mail server to use, if any. If that is set up properly, then you don't need to do anything more. If you cannot edit your php.ini file or need to target a different SMTP server for outbound email, look into the [SMTP Authentication Support module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email settings.

I've had the same problem where Drupal doesn't send any email. I changed domains a year ago, but I forgot to change the default email. I just set the new default email as `something@mynewsite.com`. If you set up email from another gate it can fall into spam, too.